# Is this class a singleton?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is the class listed below a singleton? Since the constructor is declared as public, can I infer that the class is a singleton with wrong implementation?

```
public class CreateDevice extends Functionality{

  private static Simulator simulator;
  ConnectionDB connect = ConnectionDB.getInstance();


  public CreateDevice(Simulator simulator){
    this.simulator = simulator;
  }

  private static CreateDevice instance;
  synchronized public static CreateDevice getInstance() {
    if(instance == null){
      instance = new CreateDevice(simulator);
    }       
      return instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: A class can not be a singleton, only objects can be when they are one of a kind. But classes can implement the singleton pattern to restrict instantiation to one object :)

Comment: Side note: `simulator` should not be `static` if it is initialized in the `CreateDevice` - constructor - either make it static and refer to it via classname `CreateDevice.simulator` OR remove the `static` keyword. (this  doesn't really have anything to do with the question of being singleton, though)

Comment: You are right. This is a problematic code which is needed to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a singleton, but then you need to find an other way to inject the simulator into it.

In the current implementation, the simulator is set the first time somebody calls the constructor. That constructor is very weird because it sets a static field. It will also immediately open a connection, separate from the connection that is used by the singleton instance.

If the getInstance() method is called before the constructor is called at least once, the simulator is never set.

To make it a proper singleton, you can remove the constructor and add a private no-args constructor. You'll also need a static setSimulator() method that sets the static field, and make sure it's called before any other interaction with the simulator is required.

If you have dependencies between singletons, I'd recommend to go for the Inversion-of-Control pattern, where an IoC container creates the service objects and wires them together.

Comment: You are right, but the problem is whether I should change it to real singleton.

Comment: If you change it to a proper singleton, it will be an improvement over the current situation. But using IoC will be even more of an improvement.

Answer (score 7):

In a word - no. Since the constructor is `public`, anyone can create a new instance of it wherever and whenever they want. Making the constructor `private` should solve the issue, and turn the class into a singleton.

Comment: The thing is the code could be wrong and I infer from other code that this class may be singleton.(You can imagine that the function of it is just create a device so there is no need for multiple instances) So I wonder do I need to change it to real singleton.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are correct in saying that this would not be a Singleton in the current implementation.

Either you need to make the constructor private (which is what is usually done), or if for legacy reasons you need a public constructor, you should create a constructor that checks if the instance is null, and either throw an exception if it already exists or create it by calling another private constructor, assign it to instance, and return it. The first option is preferable, althouth the other works fine for most projects where a refactor is too expensive.